# Is it possible to implement implicit cursor without where clause in select query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am unable to include condition to fetch required records without utilizing **"Where"** clause when using implicit cursor...

Comment: As is, it's not that clear what you need to do. Please edit your question by adding some code to show us what you tried to do, what you need  and the issues you're having,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. *"Implicit cursor"* can mean a range of things, and *"unable to include condition"* doesn't tell us much about the problem you are having. Some sample code and the exact error message would help a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to implement implicit cursor without where clause in select query?

Yes.

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab 
( 
   name    VARCHAR2 (10), 
   address   VARCHAR2 (10) 
);   


BEGIN

   INSERT INTO test_tab
        VALUES ('A', 'xyz');

   INSERT INTO test_tab
        VALUES ('B', 'mno');

   INSERT INTO test_tab
        VALUES ('C', 'abc');

   COMMIT;
END;
```

--without where condition

```
DECLARE 
   TYPE test_nt IS TABLE OF test_tab %ROWTYPE; 

   l_test   test_nt; 
BEGIN 
     SELECT * 
       BULK COLLECT INTO l_test
       FROM test_tab ;       

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_test.COUNT); 
END;
```

--with where condition

```
DECLARE 
   l_name  test_tab.name%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT name 
     INTO l_name 
     FROM test_tab
    WHERE address = 'xyz'; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_name);     

END;
```